# Which medals are given when there are multiple tied positions that would earn them?

Tags: olympics, world-cup, scoring

In some sports it is (actually, not just theoretically) possible that two contestants receive the same total score.

- If this happened in the first three positions, would each medal be awarded to two people, for a total of six medals?
- Is this treated differently in the Olympics, World Cups,and other competitions?
- Is it different for each sport?

I am specifically thinking of sports in which a fixed difficulty is multiplied or added to a discrete "execution" score, for example, platform diving or figure skating or gymnastics.

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad" - it will be different for every sport.

Comment: "Will be" or "is"?

Comment: @steffen definitely "is". Some may have similar/identical processes, and I can think of three sets of sports that do so because of shared history, but that's already too broad as Phillip mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is different from competition to competition.

In the 2009 World Championships in Athletics for instance, during the [men's high jump final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_World_Championships_in_Athletics_%E2%80%93_Men's_high_jump#Medalists) there were 4 medalists: one gold, on silver, two bronce.

In competitions including time measurement (running/cycling/driving), the measurements have become so precise that I can't recall a single tie in the past decades, especially because of the "photo finish". For instance, during the [8th stage of the 2005 Tour de France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_Tour_de_France,_Stage_1_to_Stage_11#Stage_8_.28July_9th.29:_Pforzheim_-_G.C3.A9rardmer_.28235.C2.A0km.29), Pieter Weening won by 0.0002 seconds or 9.6 millimeters before Andreas Klöden.

On a side note:

To avoid ties, some sports have introduced ways to make a definite difference between participants/teams. For instance, european football/soccer has the "UEFA coefficient" which is a unique score for each team and is calculated over a certain time period, involving goals, cards and what not. This coefficient is the last determining factor when making decisions in the group phase of the UEFA European Championship if two teams have identical statistics otherwise. Rule 13.01 of the [UEFA EFC regulations](http://www.uefa.org/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/03/92/81/2039281_DOWNLOAD.pdf) states:

> If two or more teams in the same group are equal on points on completion of the
>   group matches, the following criteria are applied, in the order given, to determine
>   the rankings:
> [a.) through i.) omitted here]
>   j.) position in the UEFA national team coefficient rankings